# Dropping a column explicitly in DataFrameMapper

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Consider the following artificial data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'pet':['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish', 
                            'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish'],
                     'children': [4., 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4],
                     'salary':   [90., 24, 44, 27, 32, 59, 36, 27]})
```

In sklearn `ColumnTransformer`, I can drop any column I want by specifying `'drop'` as the transformer as follows:

```py
clmn_trnsfrmr = ColumnTransformer([
        ('clmn_drpr', 'drop', ['pet'])]),
        ('scale', StandardScaler(), ['salary']),
'passthrough'])
```

Is there a similar way in `sklearn-pandas` `DataFrameMapper` to drop **exactly the column I want**?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation 
https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-pandas/1.5.0/
says 
"Only columns that are listed in the DataFrameMapper are kept. To keep a column but don’t apply any transformation to it, use None as transformer", so just don't list the column you want to get rid of.

Comment: But that won't work if you intend to put `default=None` to passthrough a large number of columns. This would passthrough any columns which is not listed specifically. I could use `default=False` ti drop any non listed columns  but it would be infeasible to list all columns and their transformer as None  if you have a large number of columns.

Comment: I see. Then why not work on a DataFrame where the irrelevant columns have been dropped already? Or if they are part of other multi-column-transformations, it might be feasible to break up the transformation into several steps.

Comment: I do this, so that I can easily see the effect of dropping or not dropping a column and applying a transformation to a column in a pipeline. It sort of becomes a hyperparameter for my preprocessing pipeline in a Grid Search. It's just more convenient and useful this way.

Comment: Did we get any solution ? I have also encountered a use case wherein I need to drop some old feature after performing some operations on them to create new features.